# How can you stop reauthetication when downloading/opening office documents in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, wss

I successfully login to my sharepoint (wss3.0) site with my AD credentials and when I try to view/open a word document in a document library, I am again prompted to re-enter my AD credentials.  Is there any way to stop this? And if not, why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your SharePoint site to the **Local intranet** zone in Internet Explorer settings.

[Best Practices for SharePoint End-User Success](http://www.thedynamicsector.com/e/wss/Shared%20Documents/Best_Practices_for_SharePoint_End-User_Success.pdf) (page 2)

Comment: Having the site in the Trusted Sites also generally works if Local Intranet isn't an option for some reason.

Comment: Cool, thanks guys, confirmed working in both Local intranet and Trusted sites zones (with IE 8)